# Cannot log in Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: login, gui

I installed NVIDIA driver(346.22) to my machine in Ubuntu 14.04. In order to install, I used console(clt+alt+f1) for my operations. After the installation, I would like to go back to the GUI(Ubuntu Desktop). I pressed clt+alt+f7. It asked me to enter the password to log in. However, it does not accept my password. Thus, I cannot log in.

Comment: installing the driver shouldn't do affect on your password... obviously you're doing or did something wrong. Did you try to reboot after you installed the nvidia driver? And does it take you to a normal login screen after the reboot?

Answer (score 0):

Press simultaneously <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd>,
Login with your user name and password, and enter following command:

```
sudo mv .Xauthority .XauthorityBak
```

then

```
sudo reboot
```

After that try again.

Comment: I tried your solution. It didn't work.